# I have a problem with <button>. I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: html, css, button

I'm just a beginner and I'm trying to add a button with url to website.

It works in browser, but for some reason Dreamweaver keeps giving me error that special characters need to be escaped. Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Here's the button code I've written (of course button class has definition in style)

`<button class="button button2", onclick="location.href=url.html">url_text</button>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<button class="button button2" onclick="location.href='url.html'">url_text</button>
```

Comment: Oh god.. just one comma.. Thank you very much this solved it. Sorry for asking stupid questions. <3